# Should raw javascript be in a .js file - How to include?

Tags: javascript, jquery, include, external

Suppose I have a page such as the following

```
<html><head></head><body><!--STUFF-->
   <script>
       if(SomeBooleanVariable) {
           $.getScript('js/file.js');
       }
    </script>
 </body></html>
```

and my file.js file simply contains raw jQuery events with no wrapping.  It is exactly as follows:

```
 $(document).on("eventHere", "classHere", function(e) {
   //Stuff
 });


 $(document).on("eventHere", "classHere", function(e) {
   //Stuff
 });
```

This is simply not working.  When I include the contents of file.js directly into the HTML it works fine however the JS does not seem to be included properly.  I have tried putting "alert(3);" at the top of file.js but it does not fire.  I have tried the following:

```
 $("head").append("<script src=\"js/file.js\" />");
 $(document).append("<script src=\"js/file.js\" />");
 -and-
 document.write("<script src=\"js/file.js\" />");
```

Comment: Try putting an alert inside your `if` right before `$.getScript`?  Do you see `file.js` being requested in your server logs?

Comment: Sounds like eval() would work but eval is evil so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: hit F12 in chrome select the network menu and see if file.js is loaded without any error.

Comment: In what browser on what operating system did this not work? It seems to me like the code you included above is not *exactly* the same code that you have in your files, but when I tried doing the same thing using the latest version of jQuery (1.8.3) and an external JavaScript file that contained only an alert statement it worked perfectly fine. Please elaborate on specifics of your code.

Comment: Your code should work as-is if jQuery is included somewhere on the page before this script. Make sure the path to your .js file is correct.

Comment: I agree with @KevinB: the code seems fine. Just curious if this works: `<p class="test">sadkjfsaklfjsdaljf</p><div class="test">ASAFDDFDFLKJL</div><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var test = true;if (test) {$.getScript("myscript.js");}</script>` if myscript.js contains: `alert("HELLO");$(document).on("click", ".test", function () {alert("WOO HOO!");});`

Comment: IF you do this: does it work: `$(document).append("<scr"+"ipt src=\"js/file.js\" type='text/javascript' ></scr"+"ipt>");` - include closing tag to properly handle in browsers.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. My file.js actually contained an error. I am using $("head").append("js/file.js");.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load that .js file dynamically, change your code to this:

```
if(SomeBooleanVariable) {
    $.getScript("ajax/test.js")
    .done(function(script, textStatus) {
        console.log(textStatus);
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        console.log("Triggered ajaxError handler.");
    });
```

And see if you get any error in console

It may be, that you are, for example, using mod_rewrite and jQuery tries to load script relative to the "folder" your subpage is in. Example: you are @ http://www.example.com/link-to-subpage/. In this case, jQuery will try to load http://www.example.com/link-to-subpage/js/file.js, while it resides @ http://www.example.com/js/file.js. In this case, use an absolute path. So, instead of:

```
js/file.js
```

write:

```
/js/file.js
```

Comment: You don't want to load a file when it's not needed. Bad practice.

Comment: Depends on how big that file is. File that only contains few lines is not going to add massive overhead, and OP didn't show the real code.

Comment: This solution will require manual changes to a million html files.  Simply not feasible.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake.  My file.js actually contained an error.  I am using $("head").append("js/file.js");.  Your way technically works too.  You can have the rep and upvotes.  Thanks!